# Xamarin Android impossible to save file PDFdocument

Tags: android, xamarin, pdf-generation

I'm new to Xamarin.
I'm trying to save my PDF document to mobile, but the PDF documents do not save in my phone.

I have already granted `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions in the android manifest.

This is my source code

```
public void CreatePdf(Survey survey)
{
    // create a new document
    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument();

    // crate a page description
    PageInfo pageInfo = new PageInfo.Builder(100, 100, 1).Create();

    // start a page
    PdfDocument.Page page = pdf.StartPage(pageInfo);

    Canvas canvas = page.Canvas;

    Paint paint = new Paint();

    canvas.DrawCircle(50, 50, 30, paint);

     // finish the page
    pdf.FinishPage(page);
    string path = "";

    try
    {  // write the document content
        path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "MediKine.pdf");

        //FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
        //pdf.WriteTo(fs);
        //fs.Flush();

        //pdf.Close();

        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
        {
            pdf.WriteTo(fileStream);
            fileStream.Flush();

            pdf.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception(e.StackTrace);
    }

    // close the document
    pdf.Close();
}
```

Code edited is working but I using an obsolete function `Forms.Context` in order to get the activity. I will try to find the good solution.

```
    try
    {  // Get directory download
        Java.IO.File file = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads);

        CheckPermission();

        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(file.AbsolutePath + "MediKine.pdf", FileMode.Create))
        {
            pdf.WriteTo(fileStream);
            fileStream.Flush();
            fileStream.Close();
            pdf.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception(e.StackTrace);
    }

    // close the document
    pdf.Close();
}

private void CheckPermission()
{
    if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.M)
    {
        const string permission = Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage;

        if (ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(Android.App.Application.Context, permission) != Android.Content.PM.Permission.Granted)
        {
            ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions((Activity)Forms.Context, new String[] { Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage }, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: thx for edit it's better !!

Comment: If the file is not saved then there should be an exception.

Comment: `have already granted READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.....`. You cannot grant permissions there. You can only request them. Moreover for Android 6+ that is not enough as you can read every day on this forum.

Comment: `fileStream.Flush();`. Im missing a `fileStream.Close();`.

Comment: I don't get exception.
I will try your solution

Comment: Not working.
the pdf is not save on my mobile...

Comment: Where are you searching for it? wWch parh? Which file explorer app did you use?

Comment: /data/user/0/com.applicationName/files/MediKine.pdf
I use esexplorer

Comment: If you mean ES File Explorer (you lazy bastard!) then that app is unable tofind it indeed.

Comment: I try file manager, root explorer.

Comment: You said you're using an "obsolete function Forms.Context" => what about Plugin.CurrentActivity (made by James Montemagno) ?